# is there any way to change/modify asset files in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

I tried for open and modify .asset files in an asset that i download from a website , but couldn't find any way. have you ever met this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Assets are anything you can use in your game, from that point of view there are options to open and modify.
However, if you are talking about files with .asset extension, these are usually files like font etc. You cant modify it.